# How to send file or use cache for mp3 files in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a php script that streams an mp3 file to the browser. I was wondering if there was a way for the browser to cache the song once played and then if not, then stream the file. I have included the function that I use to stream the mp3 files. As well as the HTML in how I implement the php script. I use a .htaccess file to get the ID of the song and then stream that based one what song it is in a database. I was imaging something to do with 304 headers correct? If anyone could possibly guide me? Thanks.

PHP:

```
private function send_file($file, $name, $contenttype = "application/octet-stream") {
    // Make sure the files exists, otherwise we are wasting our time
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        error_log('file not found');
      header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      exit;
    }

    // Get the 'Range' header if one was sent
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']; // IIS/Some Apache versions
    else if ($apache = apache_request_headers()) { // Try Apache again
      $headers = array();
      foreach ($apache as $header => $val) $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
      if (isset($headers['range'])) $range = $headers['range'];
      else $range = FALSE; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set
    } else $range = FALSE; // We can't get the header/there isn't one set

    // Get the data range requested (if any)
    $filesize = filesize($file);
    if ($range) {
      $partial = true;
      list($param,$range) = explode('=',$range);
      if (strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes') { // Bad request - range unit is not 'bytes'
        error_log('range unit not in bytes');
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
        exit;
      }
      $range = explode(',',$range);
      $range = explode('-',$range[0]); // We only deal with the first requested range
      if (count($range) != 2) { // Bad request - 'bytes' parameter is not valid
        error_log('bytes range parameter is not valid');
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
        exit;
      }
      if ($range[0] === '') { // First number missing, return last $range[1] bytes
        $end = $filesize - 1;
        $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
      } else if ($range[1] === '') { // Second number missing, return from byte $range[0] to end
        $start = intval($range[0]);
        $end = $filesize - 1;
      } else { // Both numbers present, return specific range
        $start = intval($range[0]);
        $end = intval($range[1]);
        if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) $partial = false; // Invalid range/whole file specified, return whole file
      }      
      $length = $end - $start + 1;
    } else $partial = false; // No range requested

    // Send standard headers
    header("Content-Type: $contenttype");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'.mp3"');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // if requested, send extra headers and part of file...
    if ($partial) {
      header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'); 
      header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize"); 
      if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'r')) { // Error out if we can't read the file
        error_log('can\'t read the file');
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
      }
      if ($start) fseek($fp,$start);
      while ($length) { // Read in blocks of 8KB so we don't chew up memory on the server
        $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
        $length -= $read;
        print(fread($fp,$read));
      }
      fclose($fp);
    } else readfile($file); // ...otherwise just send the whole file

    // Exit here to avoid accidentally sending extra content on the end of the file
    exit;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio src="/media/play/12345" loop />
```

Comment: I don't think people want websites to be able to store large files on their computers. You could use for example a Java plugin to do this though.

Comment: If it was going public I would agree, but it's just private at the moment, so I was just wondering if there was a way. I could give users a choice. Just trying to save on bandwidth.

Comment: There's a few methods but I am currently not keen to write them out in great detail. First there's using EXPIRES headers far into the future in combination with http NOT MODIFIED (304). There's also a way to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage Web Storage for what you need. It's a Javascript api to save stuff...